# Exclude files from deployment of ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.2 white label app with a separate config.json file. I want to be able to exclude this file from being deployed when I call dotnet publish (from VS Code) so that I don't accidentally overwrite my UAT and Prod setups.

With ASP.NET you could add `<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>` inside `<PropertyGroup>`. I've tried this in my .csproj file but it doesn't seem to be working and I can't find any reference to this element in the asp.net core docs. It looks like it might be an outstanding issue according to https://github.com/aspnet/vsweb-publish/issues/73

In previous versions of Core you could use publishExclude in the project.json file but that doesn't exist in ver 2.2

How can I exclude files on a dotnet publish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Asp.Net Core 2.2`, it uses `MSBuild` to build the project.

For ingoring the specific file, you could edit the `*.csproj` with adding below

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="config.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```